# `$XAUTHORITY` appears from 'nowhere' on su+tmux

Tags: shell, login, tmux, variable, su

When I switched from `su+bash` to `su+tmux+zsh` I noticed that I get the `$XAUTHORITY` variable defined as `/root/.xauthXXXXXX` where `XXXXXX` are 6 random alphanumeric characters. With the previous configuration, X worked with root flawlessly, but now I need to copy `~username/.Xauthority` to `$XAUTHORITY`.

The variable is defined nowhere; I checked `.zshrc`, `/etc/profile*`, `/etc/profile.d/*` etc.

```
# env
TERM=screen
SHELL=/usr/bin/tmux
USER=toor
TMUX=/tmp//tmux-0/default,6495,3
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
PWD=/root
SHLVL=2
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=toor
DISPLAY=:0.0
XAUTHORITY=/root/.xauthUSzLl4
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
_=/bin/env
OLDPWD=/root
EDITOR=vim
vcs_info_msg_0_=
vcs_info_msg_1_=

% echo $XAUTHORITY 
/home/mpiechotka/.Xauthority
% su 
password:
# echo $XAUTHORITY 
/root/.xauthUSzLl4
# ls $XAUTHORITY
ls: cannot access /root/.xauthUSzLl4: No such file or directory
# cat .tmux.conf 
set -g default-command /bin/zsh
set -g default-shell /bin/zsh
```

`su` is aliased to `su - toor` and it opens `tmux` as shell. toor is an alias of root with different shell.

I just discovered that it appears on normal su as well. It did not do that some time ago.

`set-environment` did not work.

`xhost +localhost` did not work, but `xhost +` (disabling all control) DID work.

Comment: Could you be more specific about when you are executing what?

Comment: It's too bad my theory didn't pan out but if you fix it, please post your solution.

Comment: @Gilles: No. I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think is happening.

When you're using `su` and `bash`, the `su`-session inherits the environment with the exception of `USER`, `HOME` and `SHELL`, thus `XAUTHORITY` still points to `~username/.Xauthority` and everything is fine.  However (from the [man](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux&sektion=1) page), when the `tmux` server is started:

> ... tmux copies the environment into the global
>        environment; in addition, each session has a session environment.  When a
>        window is created, the session and global environments are merged with
>        the session environment overriding any variable present in both.

and I suspect (without knowing invocation details) that when you switch credentials, `su` tries to find `.Xauthority` in `/root` and since it can't find one when you need to run an `X` app, it creates one.  I can think of a couple ways you can try to fix this:

1. Invoke `su` by using `su -`.  This will copy over the real user's evironment
2. Add `set-environment <name> <value>` to your `tmux` config.

Unfortunately, I can't test this since I recently switched over to [i3](http://i3.zekjur.net/) (which is awesome) and I don't have a spare machine.

Comment: Except that I'm invoking su by su -. Also `echo "$XAUTHORITY"` shows there is no `~`. I'll try `set-enviroment`.

Comment: Actually I meant `~` as a shorthand to (what I presumed) was your home directory.  I've edited.

Comment: no, i3 is i3, awesome is awesome =P .

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a misconfigured [pam_xauth](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_xauth.html) PAM module. It is supposed to copy your keys to a temporary file when you run `su`. The behavior you describe is consistent with pam_xauth creating the temporary file but somehow not copying the keys (perhaps because you have a `~/.xauth/export` or a `/root/.xauth/import`).

Comment: I don't have neither of those but xauth is loaded in su session (i.e. it is in /etc/pam.d/su).

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me but this time with $COLORTERM variable.

If you start tmux on a terminal emulator that has, for instance, COLORTERM=terminus and after that you start another tmux session even on another terminal client that normally would have COLORTERM=gnome-terminal, this new session will crossover and inherit COLORTERM=terminus.

These assertions are enough to conclude that, unfortunately, tmux sessions are not isolated from each other, even if you're using different terminal emulators.

Your su sub shell is probably inheriting $XAUTHORITY from another tmux session, more specifically the very first tmux session created.