# XAUTHORITY environment variable set repeatedly on every login

Tags: ssh, xorg, x11, xauth

I am running a Suse Linux 11.04 system. My problem is that when I do a fresh login into a shell as root, a new Xauthority file of the form `xauth*****` gets created in the `/root/` directory. Upon exiting from the shell, a few `.xauth` files remain behind. I tried it on other systems but this does not happen. Also, why is the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable set only for `root` and not for my other users in the system?

`man xdm` says the following about the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable

> DisplayManager.DISPLAY.userAuthDir
>
> When xdm is unable to write to the usual user authorization file ($HOME/.Xauthority), it creates a unique file name in this directory and 
>   points the  environment variable XAUTHORITY at the created file.  It uses /tmp by default.

So in my system I do this:

```
xauth
```

Using authority file `/root/.xauthPpRsfU`

```
xauth>
```

I exit `[Ctrl+d]` and I log back in, I see that now it is starting to use a different `.xauth*` file.

```
xauth
```

Using authority file `/root/.xauthq1xt4z`

```
xauth>
```

Why does it need to keep on creating a diffent `xauth` file every time I login? Also, why is it in root when the default location is `/tmp/`? I have not set `.DisplayManagaer.DISPLAY.userAuthDir` to `/tmp` in the `xdm` configuration file.

I don't see this behaviour on any other system. In RHEL and Ubuntu all is fine.

For pointers I am not the only one who faces this issue. I guess this post is similar: [`$XAUTHORITY` appears from 'nowhere' on su+tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2269/xauthority-appears-from-nowhere-on-sutmux).

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: `/root` is the home directory for the user `root`, therefore the location is not surprising.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `su` to login as root, then it’s likely due to the use of [`pam_xauth`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_xauth) to set up a new xauthority file for that session, as described in [this old e-mail thread](https://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-selinux-list/2004-June/msg00229.html).

Answer (score 0):

Long back, I had asked the same question. Who exports/has this variable set in their process environment. Fortunately, I was taught to have a shell script. This works on Solaris. On Linux, it could be little different to parse the process' parent environment.

I could even give you the conversation I had then: https://groups.google.com/group/comp.unix.shell/browse_thread/thread/a91bf497add5544e/56dd2f64c4029734?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=mnikhil+who+exported+this+variable&pli=1#56dd2f64c4029734

```
envtrace(){ 
ptree $$ | 
while read pid prog 
do 
  /usr/ucb/ps eww $pid 
done | 
sed -n ' 
s/^ *// 
/^[^0-9]/d 
h 
s/ .*/:/p 
g 
s/^.* \('"$1"'=[^ ]*\).*/\1/p 
g 
/^'"$$"' /q' 
}
```

envtrace PATH 
envtrace OSTYPE

Comment: On Linux: `grep -lsz '^AUTHORITY=' /proc/[0-9]*/environ | cut -d / -f 3`

Comment: i believe that your command above gives me the pid of the process that has changed / updated the XAUTHROTIY environment variable . Could be help me with the logic behind this kind of usage . Seems a handy command .